# How can I get this footer to be 100% width?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website with bootstrap and this is going to be the footer for the page. I got it from the bootstrap docs and changed it.

As of now, it is not 100% and I can't figure out what class is making it have a margin.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container bg-warning border border-5 border-dark mt-3">
  enter code here`<footer class="py-2 my-2">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3 border-dark">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-dark fw-bold">Homepage</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-dark fw-bold">Contact us here</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="text-center text-dark fw-bold">&copy; copyright filler</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using a css file? if so, could you please show your own css file?

Comment: it depends on your site content

Answer (score 0):

Remove the container class and the mt-3 class on the first div.

**Like so**:

```
<div class=" bg-warning border border-5 border-dark">
  enter code here`<footer class="py-2 my-2">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3 border-dark">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-dark fw-bold">Homepage</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-dark fw-bold">Contact us here</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="text-center text-dark fw-bold">&copy; copyright filler</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

If you wanted that margin on the top, just add the mt-3 class again.

Comment: Yup I just figured it out thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use container-fluid class instead of container class